# Backpack for Laravel - Upload CSV and Store as JSON in Database

Tags: laravel, csv, import, laravel-backpack

I have successfully configured Backpack for Laravel to handle all of the CRUD  ops for my app except for one particular field. I need to import a CSV, convert it to JSON and then store the JSON in my database to later display as an HTML table.

I created a custom field in Backpack, which does in fact create a field to upload the file, but I can't figure out how to point it to a custom method to handle the logic to handle the conversion and storing of the CSV.

I have combed the documentation but I don't see any mention of anything like this. https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type

```
//Placed in the Controller CrudPanel Configuration
$this->crud->addField([
  // CSV to JSON
  'label' => "Specs Table",
  'name' => "specifications_table",
  'type' => 'csv2json', //custom field name
], 'update/create/both');

//Placed in csv2json.blade.php file
<div @include('crud::inc.field_wrapper_attributes') >
  <label>{!! $field['label'] !!}</label>
  <input
      type="file"
      name="{{ $field['name'] }}"
      value="{{ old($field['name']) ? old($field['name']) : (isset($field['value'])     ? $field['value'] : (isset($field['default']) ? $field['default'] : '' )) }}    "
      @include('crud::inc.field_attributes')
  >

  {{-- HINT --}}
     @if (isset($field['hint']))
        <p class="help-block">{!! $field['hint'] !!}</p>
     @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need extra logic for a custom field type, it's always a good idea (imho) to do it inside the model, as an accessor for that particular model attribute.

Take the [`image`](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.5/crud-fields#image) field type as an example: it requires you to have a `setImageAttribute()` accessor, where the actual uploading and storing is done.

You could add a new method on your model:

```php
public function setSpecificationsTableAttribute($value) {
  // read $value
  // convert it to JSON
  // $this->attributes['specifications_table'] = $fileConvertedToJson;
}
```

Hope it helps.